# "consider x as y" or "consider x to be y"

Tags: prepositions

Which of these alternatives seems more correct or natural?

> We consider death as an enemy
>   We consider death an enemy
>   We consider death to be an enemy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three are grammatical.  I regard the latter two forms as meaning “We believe death is an enemy”.  In writing, I'd use the sleeker second form, not that fat, verbose third form.

The first form may be taken to have the mentioned meaning, but it can have a second meaning as well.  That is, the form *consider X as Y* is sometimes used to mean *analyze the Y aspect of X*, and sometimes as *believe X is Y*.

Comment: Well put. Let me summarize (with just a dash of prescriptiveness): To avoid ambiguity and verbosity, use the second form.

Answer (score 2):

All three are valid, mean the same thing, and would be readily understood by most English-speaking people. Take your pick.

Comment: Thanks. Can I pressure you into picking one as a personal preference?

Comment: I know this wasn't aimed at me, but... I would say 'to be' is the more correct option, because 'enemy' is a state that matches 'to be'. The other two are more about viewpoint, and I think would be better as 'seen as' or 'viewed as'.

Comment: I'd be more likely to say "to be", but it's a very close choice.

Comment: I agree as far as the sample sentences go, but it would certainly be possible to construct an ambiguous sentence using "consider as."